# Create request with basic authentication with Fiddler

Tags: web-services, rest, post, http-post, fiddler

How to construct a POST request to an endpoint, as the request is secured with basic authentication (username, password) and the type is XML.
It has to be done in Fiddler.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct a web request under the Composer tab.
There you can select the type from the drop-down - in your case POST.
In the text box on the right enter the endpoint url address.
In the text area below enter the headers, like this:

```
Content-type: text/xml
Authentication: Basic  BASE64USERNAMEPASSWORDHERE
```

The format of the authentication is: username:password encoded in Base64 format. For the encoding you can also use Fiddler - Go to Tools -> TextWizard...

Finally press Execute button on the right side and you will get the result response.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've added couple additional headers and a body and it seems to work.